# Why is the source folder in the lib folder in eclipse gradle project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, buildship

When trying to create a gradle project in eclipse, the source folder, build.gradle and others are stored in a different folder called *lib* as a separate project.
How can I make all the folders be within the project folder like in a normal java project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the *New Gradle Project* dialog invokes the Gradle `init` task with the hard-coded argument `--type java-library` and that the project layout for Gradle versions higher than 6.6.1 has a `lib` folder besides the main project folder for a project of the type `java-library` (in contrast to in Gradle 6.6.1 or lower and in contrast to a project of the type `application` independent of the Gradle version).

In the future, in the *New Gradle Project* dialog, the type `application` should also be chooseable, to get a simple project structure like in the past. But this is not implemented yet:
[Eclipse Buildship issue #1118: **Add more project templates to New Gradle Project wizard**](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1118)

As a **workaround** do the following:

1. In the *New Gradle Project* dialog on the second or third page, check *Override workspace settings* and

   - choose as ***Specific Gradle version*** the version ***6.6.1*** and
   - for ***Java home*** a **Java 11** JDK
2. In the **`build.gradle`** change `id 'java-library'` to **`id 'application'`**
3. In ***Project > Properties: Gradle*** choose a higher Gradle version

The last two steps are only required to use a Gradle version higher than 6.6.1.

Comment: Thanks, can I change the jdk version after?

Comment: Yes, a Java 17 JDK with Gradle 7.5-rc-3 works for me, but I don't know whether all combinations of Java and Gradle versions will work. After changing _Java home_ in the project properties _Gradle_, right-click the project and choose _Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project_.